# Display the description of taxonomy terms

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I have a taxonomy called ORGANIZER.
All the terms of this taxonomy have a name and a description.
I tried to get the description of each term but i don't know how to loop on them.

I suppose i mus begin with:

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'organizer',
    'hide_empty' => false,
) );
```

but could you help me for the loop please ?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

[`get_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) returns an array of [`WP_Term`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term/) objects. To get the description, with the usual filters applied, you can pass this object to [`term_description()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/term_description/):

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'organizer',
    'hide_empty' => false,
) );

if ( ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        echo term_description( $term );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@jacob peattie

Sorry I have no rights to add comments so i add another answer, i don't know how do to better...

It seems that `get_terms()` returns nothing but the organizer taxonomy exists and is not empty.